# Onchange value in datepicker doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I tried many solutions to get an alert on `on change` value event in date picker but it doesn't work, have you an idea

```
<div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="input-text required-entry" name="delivery[date]">
</div>

jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var date = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
         var todaydate = "<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>";
         dayOfWeek = weekday[date.getUTCDay()];
         jQuery('#datepicker').attr('data-day',dayOfWeek);
         gettimeslots();
      },
});
```

**I tested:**

```
$('#datepicker').on('input',function(e){
     alert('Changed');
    });

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
        alert('Changed');
    }});
```

Comment: what `datepicker` plugin you are using?

Comment: i don't know, where i can find it ?

Comment: ok.. can you check if there any console errors in browser? Just click F12 on browser and navigate to console tab and see if you have any errors!

Comment: No, this is the first thing that I looked at

Comment: do you see any script files with name `datetimepicker.js` included in `html`?

Comment: When i try this `$('#datepicker').on('input',function(e){
     alert('Changed');
    });` it works if i edit the input with the keyboard, but if i select the date with the mouse via the datepicker grid it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138719/discussion-between-prince-and-guruprasad-rao).